# How to calculate rolling window periods for dates in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, rolling-computation

I am new to python, so would appreciate some help!
I want to calculate dates period on a rolling basis.
I have an input data such as below:

```
Date        RF1     RF2
01-01-2008  TRUE    FALSE   
02-01-2008  TRUE    FALSE   
03-01-2008  FALSE   FALSE   
04-01-2008  FALSE   FALSE   
05-01-2008  FALSE   FALSE   
06-01-2008  FALSE   FALSE   
07-01-2008  FALSE   FALSE   
08-01-2008  FALSE   FALSE   
09-01-2008  FALSE   FALSE   
10-01-2008  FALSE   FALSE   
11-01-2008  FALSE   FALSE
```

I want to calculate different periods of dates of 250 days on a rolling basis of 20 days and then check how many times False comes in that period.

For ex: my first period is Jan 1 2008+250 days

Then my second period should be from Jan 21+250 days and so forth

Then for each period I need to check the number of times False occurs for each column.

PLEASE HELP!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rolling` and `sum`, then `resample` and `first` to process the dataframe with vectorized Pandas methods, provided the `Date` column contains true `Timestamp` objects. It it contains strings, you must first convert them to timestamps with:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

I will also assume that the `RF1` and `RF2` columns contain true booleans. Here again if they are strings, you should first convert them to booleans:

```
df['RF1'] = df['RF1'] == 'TRUE'    # same for RF2
```

I have build a sample dataframe close to yours with:

```
np.random.seed(0)          # make data reproducible

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.date_range('2008-01-01', periods=500, freq='D'),
    'RF1': np.random.choice([True, False], 500),
    'RF2': np.random.choice([True, False], 500)})
```

It gives:

```
          Date    RF1    RF2
0   2008-01-01   True  False
1   2008-01-02  False  False
2   2008-01-03  False   True
3   2008-01-04   True   True
4   2008-01-05  False   True
..         ...    ...    ...
495 2009-05-10   True   True
496 2009-05-11  False   True
497 2009-05-12   True   True
498 2009-05-13  False  False
499 2009-05-14   True   True
```

I would first compute the rolling sum of True values for each full period of 250 days, and then resample the result on every 20th day:

```
# compute the sum of True values per periods of 250 days with start and end
result = df.rolling(250, on='Date').sum().dropna().rename(
    columns={'Date': 'End'}).assign(Start=df['Date'] - pd.Timedelta(249, 'D'))

# reorder columns
result = result.reindex(columns=['Start', 'End', 'RF1', 'RF2'])

# resample on every 20th day
result.resample('20D', on='Start').first().reset_index(drop=True)
```

It gives:

```
        Start        End    RF1    RF2
0  2008-01-01 2008-09-06  126.0  123.0
1  2008-01-21 2008-09-26  124.0  120.0
2  2008-02-10 2008-10-16  126.0  122.0
3  2008-03-01 2008-11-05  127.0  121.0
4  2008-03-21 2008-11-25  121.0  129.0
5  2008-04-10 2008-12-15  122.0  122.0
6  2008-04-30 2009-01-04  120.0  122.0
7  2008-05-20 2009-01-24  120.0  120.0
8  2008-06-09 2009-02-13  119.0  119.0
9  2008-06-29 2009-03-05  118.0  127.0
10 2008-07-19 2009-03-25  112.0  124.0
11 2008-08-08 2009-04-14  114.0  134.0
12 2008-08-28 2009-05-04  113.0  133.0
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. But I didnt not understand the numerical values in the columns in RF1 and RF2. What I precisely want is to find out the 'periods' and then find out the no of times False comes in each column of each period. I dont seem to understand the output of this code

Comment: @PSharma: My code counts the number of `True` in each period.

Comment: Hey Thanks, but where can I see the "period"? I mean I see there are 2 column of dates now. I would want to see the start and end date of each period and the True counts. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hi, Again Thank you so much!. I have another query. Please excuse me, since I am bit confused and very new to Python. Why is the start and end date in the above output same? I mean the end date should be 250 days more than the start date right? Also I would need the number of times True comes in that particular period. I tried running this code with my data, but its not giving me the correct answer!

Comment: @PSharma I think that you only want full periods, while I computed partial ones. See my last edit.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot it worked! :) I have an additional query.. how do I filter the rows with values less than 24. I tried result[result<24]] but it gives me an error ----Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and int

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have `data` like belows;

```py
data = [
    {'Date': '01-01-2008', 'RF1': True, 'RF2': False},
    ...
]
```

And then you can calculate the number of false

```py
from itertools import islice

apply_data = [list(islice(data, n, n+250)) for n in range(0, len(data), 20)]
for each_list in apply_data:
    rf1_true_count = sum(v['RF1'] for v in each_list)
    rf1_false_count = 250 - rf1_true_count 
    print(rf1_false_count )

    rf2_true_count = sum(v['RF2'] for v in each_list)
    rf2_false_count = 250 - rf2_true_count 
    print(rf2_false_count )
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your help. Although the code is giving me an error. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'. I have no clue why this is happening

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your code, the code still gives me an error. in the line "rf1_true_count = sum(v['RF1'] for v in each_list)". I tried printing apply_data, but it seems to be an empty list

Comment: I suppose that 'RF1' and 'RF2' has boolean value.